# Design-Time Property String Array the object returned null for the property but this is not allowed

Tags: c#, properties, design-time

my custom control inherits from a DataGridView.  Within this custom control,  I'm trying to create a property on my  which allows specifying a list of string:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public string[] MyProperty{get; set;}
```

I'm finding that whenever i make a change on the form on which one or more of this control's hosted, I get an error:

> The object 'column name' returned null for the property 'MyProperty' but this is not allowed.

I am now handling this by putting the following code in the constructor:

```
if(MyProperty == null)
{
    MyProperty = new string[]{};
}
```

This seems to resolve the issue.  Is there a better way?

cheers

Comment: can you supply a default value?

Comment: Also: Do you have an idea just what the connection of MyProperty is with the object 'column name' is?

Comment: Hi TaW, I did try supply a default value, I'm unsure what your second question is asking.  I've updated the question though.

Comment: The DefaultValue attribute does not *set* a default value.  It's used by the Designer to determine whether or not the value should be saved in the designer file.  If a property value does not match the DefaultValue, the property becomes **bold** in the grid.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification LarsTech.  How would you supply a default value when the control's first placed on a form?

Comment: In the constructor of the class, which in your case, is you custom data grid control.

Comment: My 2nd question was simply trying to understand the error message, but it may be just some internal. I don't think you need a better way, it looks ok to me; was the check for null necessary?